# Connect to SQL Server from Powerpoint

Tags: sql-server, vba, powerpoint

How can I connect to a SQL DB from Powerpoint (be it 2007 or 2010) to generate reports? I've seen quite a few forums and most of them talk about using external tools.

Check http://www.officekb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/powerpoint/34863/Linking-PowerPoint-to-a-database

http://www.ljzsoft.com/pptreport/help/ppt-report-help.htm

Isnt there any out of the box solution for this?

P.S. I've also posted this at the [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officegeneral/thread/2e4bf40f-442f-42b6-8f89-d04a0d2068f5). Didnt get any replies hence posting it here

Comment: One way I can think of from the top of my head would be to insert an "OLE Object" and make it a link to an excel file. The excel file in turn have a SQL Datasource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start looking into [VBA for PowerPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814734.aspx#odc_Office14_ta_GettingStartedWithVBAInPowerPoint2010_FindingObjects). This helps with referencing the objects and manipulating PP. You'll need to look into using SQL Server for VBA if you want to provide the content for TextFrames, grids, or Excel Charts.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I'll explore this option and see if it serves the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I would Just do it in Excel, then embed the Excel object in PP Slide. Or Convert the Reports to Images use those.

Coding report in PowerPoint just seems wrong.

Comment: I agree with that you said, but I was thinking more on the lines of being able to generate the reports at runtime rather than have it in excel and then put it onto a powerpoint.

Comment: PowerPoint is going to use Excel anyway for Charts. They're fairly well integrated.