# Pre-Populate a PowerPoint Deck with dynamic data

Tags: refresh, powerpoint, dynamic-data

I need to build a PowerPoint template/Presentation that pre-populates upon creation.   Some slides will get tabular data from a SQL data source.   Other slides have a "Gantt" style schedule object that must refresh from the same data source.

Is this possible using only Microsoft components?
What in general would be a good approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747946/connect-to-sql-server-from-powerpoint

Comment: My question is a bit different due to the embedded Gantt chart.